# Update Const template at Magento 2 Class

Tags: magento2, template, class, plugin

I need to update a template defined in a Constant at Configurable Class(Magento/Swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php).

I tried with a Plugin, but how the function which gets the constant is protected, I can't update the Constant correctly.

Anyone knows the correct way to update this constant or rewrite the function to change the path to my Module template.

> const CONFIGURABLE_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';
>
> protected function getRendererTemplate()
>      {
>          return $this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute ?
>              self::SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE : 
>              self::CONFIGURABLE_RENDERER_TEMPLATE;
>      }

Comment: The function getRendererTemplate runs into _toHtml() how a parameter of setTemplate().

Answer (score 7):

You can create before plugin on setTemplate method and overwrite template argument.

Create plugin

```
class ProductSwatchPlugin
{
    public function beforeSetTemplate(
        \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable $subject,
        $template
    ) {
         return ['You_Module::template.phtml'];
    }
}
```

and declare it in DI.xml

```
<type name="\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
    <plugin name="you_module_change_template" type="ProductSwatchPlugin" />
</type>
```

See more details in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html)

Comment: Can you specify how to do it?
When I do beforeSetTemplate(){...} I'm overwriting the template of the page and not of the output of _toHtml() function...

Comment: I add details to answer. _toHtml()  call setTemplate

Answer (score 6):

An alternative is to override it using dependency injection.

Modify `di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable" type="vendorName\moduleName\Block\Rewrite\Product\Renderer\Configurable" />
</config>
```

Create `app/code/vendorName/moduleName/Block/Rewrite/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php`

```
namespace vendorName\moduleName\Block\Rewrite\Product\Renderer;

class Configurable extends \Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable {

    protected function getRendererTemplate() {
        return $this->isProductHasSwatchAttribute ?
                self::SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE : 'vendorName_moduleName::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';
    }

}
```

Create `app/code/vendorName/moduleName/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` to override the template.